# Modify elements without page movement using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to change the data of DB without page movement.
I'll give you an example.

I am taking data from DB and showing it on screen
[Data from DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5LFM.png)

When I double click the data, the plain text turns into a modifiable form.
[when I double click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ONbA.png)

Form contains existing data and can be modified.
[modify text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PqtV.png)

After modification, pressing the enter key to change data in DB.
[press enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L273e.png)

Comment: I believe you're trying to update the data using ajax. right?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating your problem? Show us what you have tried already.

Comment: Also, if you have not already done so, please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you!